vscode: namespace "std" has no member "barrier"C/C++(135)
Ubuntu 22.04.4
VSCode 1.88.1
g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
VSCode is flagging std::barrier saying the namespace "std" has no member "barrier" C/C++(135.
#include <iostream>
#include <barrier>
#include <pthread.h>

std::barrier my_barrier(3); 
  
void* my_function(void*) 
{ 
    my_barrier.arrive_and_wait(); 
    return NULL;
} 
  
int main() {

Here is the pertinent section of my c_cpp_properties.json file:
"includePath": [
    "${workspaceFolder}",
    "${workspaceFolder}/include",
    "/usr/include",
    "/usr/include/c++/11",
    "/usr/include/c++/11/backward",
    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu",
    "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/11",
    "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include",
    "/usr/local/include"
],
"defines": [],
"cStandard": "c23",
"intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64",
"configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
"cppStandard": "c++20",
"compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++-11",
"compilerArgs": [
    "-std=c++20",
    "-Wall",

There are no errors or warning compiling the code. No other standard library functions are being flagged. Barrier is part of C++20, and GCC 11 supports C++20. What am I missing or overlooking?
Thanks!

It's possible that "If you have specified a configurationProvider, the configurations that provides will take precedence over your other settings in c_cpp_properties.json" is the problem.

I can only reproduce this same error when not using the -std=c++20 compiler flag.  I know there are a couple places that you can set the C++ version and I suspect you are not getting the right one.  Here is another piece of code that relies on C++20 being set.  If you get the same error message then most likely you have not set the standard in the correct part.  Are you using the code runner extension?

@molbdnilo Thanks. I deleted the configurationProvider line from c_cpp_properties.json, saved it closed and re-opend vscode and the issue remains.

@NathanOliver Thanks. No error with std::endian::native. I'm not using the code runner extension.

Do you have other extensions?

These are all the extensions. Disabling them has no effect except for C/C++ Intellisense and Extension pack which of course disables the checking.
C/C++ IntelliSense v1.19.9 & C/C++ Extension Pack v1.3.0,
C/C++ Themes v2.0.0,
Doxygen Documentation Generator v1.4.0,
GitHub Copilot v1.181.0 & GitHub Copilot Chat v0.14.1,
Vim v1.27.2

Wow, this was a strange issue, but I've re-solved it, though I can't tell you the steps to re-create it.
I decided I should bite the bullet and make a small test case to send to the C/C++ extension developers. I did a cp -r of the directory to make a copy of the issue, and then planned to pare it down to something minimal.
I'm going to use the barrier function, and this issue started when I wrote some test code to experiment with it. I named the executable of that test code "barrier".
In the new test case directory when the barrier executable was deleted, the 'namespace "std" has no member "barrier" C/C++(135)' error disappeared. Interestingly when I copied copied the executable file named barrier back into this directory, the error did not come back. There must have been some sequence of steps that caused this issue. The c_cpp_properties.json and a few other things have been changed since the error appeared. I went to the original directory and deleted the barrier executable and the error disappeared. I regenerated the barrier executable and the error did not come back.
Again, I don't know the sequence of steps that caused this, but I know I won't be naming any executables the same name as the standard library function anymore. Actually it was probably because the executable was the same name as the include file.

"Actually it was probably because the executable was the same name as the include file." -- I strongly doubt that this was the case. However, I don't have any better explanation, either. It would probably be useful to see exactly with which command-line arguments the compiler was being invoked when the error occurred. I guess there exists probably some kind of build log. However, I am unfamiliar with VS Code.

It wasn't during compile. It was an intellisense error. I don't compile using VSCode. There is a makefile for the project which never produced any errors or warnings.

are you using makefile tools as your configurationProvider? (because I think that would be a good idea). if you put something like ${workspaceFolder}/** in your c_cpp_configuration.json's includePath, that could be the reason.
